# Unloading/removing shared libraries from process

Tags: c, linux, linker, shared-libraries

So here my problem.  I have a Linux program running on a VM which uses OpenCL via dlopen to execute some commands.  About half way through the program's execution it will sleep, and upon resume can make no assumptions about any state on the GPU (in fact, the drivers may have been reloaded and the physical GPU may have changed).  Before sleeping dlclose is called and this does unload the OpenCL memory regions (which is a good thing), but the libraries OpenCL uses (cuda and nvidia libraries in this case) are NOT unloaded.  Thus when the program resumes and tries to reinitalize everything again, things fail.
So what I'm looking for is a method to effectively unlink/unload the shared libraries that OpenCL was using so it can properly "restart" itself.  As a note, the process itself can be paused (stopped) during this transition for as long as needed, but it may not be killed.
Also, assume I'm working with root access and have more or less no restrictions on what files I can modify/touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a less short-term practical solution, you could probably try forcing re-initialization sequence on a loaded library, and/or force unloading.

libdl is just an ordinary library you can copy, modify, and link against instead of using the system one. One option is disabling `RTLD_NODELETE` handling. Another is running `DT_FINI`/`DT_INIT` sequence for a given library.

`dl_iterate_phdr`, if available, can probably be used to do the same without the need to modify libdl.

Poking around in libdl and/or using `LD_DEBUG` (if supported) may shed some light on why it is not being unloaded in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't unload, this is either because something is keeping a reference to them, or they have the `nodelete` flag set, or because the implementation of `dlclose` does not support unloading them for some other reason. Note that there is no requirement that `dlclose` ever unload anything:

> An application writer may use dlclose() to make a statement of intent on the part of the process, but this statement does not create any requirement upon the implementation. When the symbol table handle is closed, the implementation may unload the executable object files that were loaded by dlopen() when the symbol table handle was opened and those that were loaded by dlsym() when using the symbol table handle identified by handle.

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlclose.html

The problem you're experiencing is a symptom of why it's an utterly bad idea to have graphics drivers loaded in the userspace process, but fixing this is both a technical and political challenge (lots of people are opposed to fixing it).

The only short-term practical solution is probably either factoring out the code that uses these libraries as a separate process that you can kill and restart, and talking to it via some IPC mechanism, or simply having your whole program serialize its state and re-exec itself on resume.